# Run iPhone SDK on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I was wondering if anyone knows if you can run the iPhone SDK on an iPad. Tried looking through apple.com, but didn't find anything useful...

I want to be able to develop -- from start to finish -- an iPhone app on the iPad and was wondering if that's possible...

Comment: Maybe Apple will make that possible... Would be great!!!
I seen on TV that Apple will allow more advanced and professional programs/apps in iPad because Apple want iPad to be more like a PC...
So let's wait and hope that Apple will make that possible...

Comment: I'm sure you've seen, but iPhone Apps will work on the iPad anyway. So just develop your app the normal way and wait until they come out and it _should_ run it just fine!

Comment: There's also an SDK out for it now, not sure if this allows higher res stuff to be done tho. Check it out http://www.apple.com/ipad/sdk/

Comment: OF course we will all like to develop on an iPad. I´m on an PC and if I would like to develop, I have to buy an Apple with Intel processor. When I now have bought an iPhone and I love it, i still wanna be on an PC and I wanna develop apps for iphone. I could buy an iPad ´cause I find i sooo coool, and would love it if it could take the SDK! That would be great! Two things in one blow (I hope you say it like that!)! But Apple don´t see the possability to get even the PC bunch on the train. I love my iPhone and will love the iPad so why can´t I develop on it?

Comment: The reason might be that soon the only reason to buy a MacBook Pro is so that you can run that SDK. The iPad seem to do most anything else smoother, faster and with much more modern usability. If they enable this on the iPad many will jump ship to the iPad plus external KB + monitor display no kidding.

Comment: You can make your iPad or iPhone a thin client using RDM+. Remotely develop using Xcode on your desktop but accessed via mobile.

Answer (score 20):

That's unlikely (read: practically impossible). iPhone SDK and Xcode developer tools are designed to run on Mac OS X on Intel x86 processors. iPad's processor is a 1GHz ARM processor. It's a different architecture and is inadequate for running those tools effectively anyway. (This can change if Apple can and be willing to develop a version of said developer tools natively for iPhone OS with sufficient performance).

You can use a text editor on an iPad to write code but you are not likely to be able to compile, test, and debug it.

---

By the way, in case the device can be jailbroken, you'd be able to run native gcc for iPhone OS to compile your app (as you can currently do with an iPhone/iPod touch too). You won't be able to use Apple's proprietary tools like Interface Builder but you'd be able to compile Objective-C sources and test and debug your app.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Could've been a very convenient way to write those apps. Since you could test them out with the gestures and such...

Comment: @johannix: I agree. I personally plan to write a syntax highlighter for C# for iPad ;)

Comment: Typing code on the "keyboard" simulation would be very, very difficult.  You're not missing much.

Comment: They've got an external keyboard you could hook up. So I was imaging you'd use the real keyboard and then when you want to test it you'd just touch the screen... Although there isn't much screen real estate so it'd probably get very annoying.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason for Apple to port the SDK to the iPad. There would be way more effort than value in this project.

As for testing on the device, this will work the same was as it does today on the iPhone. You will install a debug App on the device and debug through the cable inside XCode.

No different for the iPad than for the iPhone in this regard.

-t

Comment: +1 because your the first to point out that one can already test on the device.

Answer (score 3):

The jailbreak developer saurik, who created Cydia, has already ported gcc to jailbroken iPhones and I'm sure it will be ported to jailbroken iPads.

Comment: @chpwn: There's no new "porting" to be done. iPad runs iPhone OS so the same thing should work. Jailbreak would suffice.

Comment: Probably, but they broke the linker in 3.1 so who knows what else they can/will do.

Comment: that Mobile Xcode app idea might actually work well on an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can run applications developed using the iPhone SDK on the iPad or whether you can run the SDK itself, i.e. Xcode and Interface Builder and develop on the iPad? The answer to the former is yes, to the latter (though Apple has not said this explicitly), you can assume the answer is no.

Comment: I want to run the SDK itself.